# DI injection using configuration settings possible in asp.net core MVC 2.1?

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core

i am creating .Net core MVC 2.1 application. Apart from my main project ( that contain Views/ Controllers/ ViewModels, i also added library project say LibA that contains class say A. 
To register class A and its corresponding mapping interface with DI i need to have reference of LibA in main project.
I do NOT want to add reference of LIBA in main project. 
Can i do DI using configuration like in appsettings.json or some similar json file?

Comment: If main project do not reference LibA, how main project using it? Usually main project where you configure DI, is an entry point of your application which "know" about all dependencies used inthe application.

Comment: i know how to do it using configuration in my App / Web.config in NON  .net Core  applications for Unity and Autofac. In .NetCore i do not know if this is possible where to put that configuration.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. You can look at [AutoFac](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io)

```
<autofac defaultAssembly="Autofac.Example.Calculator.Api">
    <components>
        <component
            type="Autofac.Example.Calculator.Addition.Add, Autofac.Example.Calculator.Addition"
            service="Autofac.Example.Calculator.Api.IOperation" />

        <component
            type="Autofac.Example.Calculator.Division.Divide, Autofac.Example.Calculator.Division"
            service="Autofac.Example.Calculator.Api.IOperation" >
            <parameters>
                <parameter name="places" value="4" />
            </parameters>
        </component>
```

Comment: Is this related to .NetCore? Which json file i should put this configuration in?

Comment: I accidentally included wrong configuration example. You can use appsettings.json (which you already have)